# Get index number from range

Tags: html, loops, templates, go, go-templates

In to get the index number php:

```
foreach much as index => each{
 //get index number from index
}
```

How can I get the index number in go?

```
{{ range .post }}
   {{ // how can i get index number? }}
   {{ .Id }}
   {{ .Name}}
{{ end}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`text/template` Variables:](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables)

> If a "range" action initializes a variable, the variable is set to the successive elements of the iteration. Also, a "range" may declare two variables, separated by a comma:
>
> ```
> range $index, $element := pipeline
> ```

So in your example:

```
{{ range $i, $e := .post }}
   Index: {{ $i }}
   {{ .Id }}
   {{ .Name}}
{{ end}}
```